# Use shape-outside with position:fixed

Tags: css

I would like a red square to have `position:fixed` in the top-right corner, text that wraps around it and rearranges when scrolling.

So far I have an exclusion using `shape-outside` (see Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/2bq1rnu7/1/)) but it does not play well with `position:fixed`.

How can I have the red box fixed in the top-right, with the text flowing around it when scrolling?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot scroll the container and keep this floatting element fixed (going down ) without some help from javascript.

Here is  a demo with a transition and a negative margin-top, triggered with an input, wich pulls up the text. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/umjDe

THIS IS NOT your solution, but it is suppose to help you understand how this can work.

```
#exclusion { 
      shape-outside: rectangle(-20px, 0, 150px, 150px, 50%, 50%);
      float: right;
      width: 150px;
      height: 150px;
      background-color: red;
}
:checked ~ article  p {
  margin: -50% 0 0;
}
p {
  transition:4s;
}
article {
  margin:0;
  border:solid;
  overflow:hidden;
}
```

---

another example that pushes down your floatting element : http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KafAn

You may via javascript tune one or the other demo , checking on amount scrolled :)

Answer (score 0):

Rearranging text is only possible with element that has block display, but then translating is impossible. Using position fixed, absolute or relative doesn't work in this case.

In my opinion the only solution is to write a javascript for that task, but it wouldn't be simple.

You can for example keep every single word in separated markup and then put the exclusion in  desired place within paragraph.